# BeautifulSoup how can I remove div element from h1 tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have tried below code for parser html using BeautifulSoup.

```
item_detail_soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
h1 = item_detail_soup.find("h1")
```

My H1 parser output is:

```
<h1>
<div class="brand" style="display: block; font-size: 0.75rem;">Apple(#34567)</div>
〔NEW〕 iPhone12 256GB </h1>
```

I'm trying to remove this div with class name `brand`.

My desired output:

```
<h1> (NEW) iPhone12 256GB </h1>
```

I have tried by extract() then replace, but I have failed.

```
h1 = item_detail_soup.find("h1")
h1 = h1.replace(item_detail_soup.find("h1").div.extract(),'')
```

How can I get my desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good news, you were on the right track - To get your goal you can go with `.extract()`, `.replace_with()` and `.decompose()` as well.

#### What is the difference extract vs decompose?

While `.extract()` removes a tag or string from the tree and returns it / keeps it as additional parse tree, `decompose()` removes the tag from the tree and destroys it and its contents completely.

#### What went wrong?

The reason why you will not get your expected result is, that you try to operate on your `h1` variable so it will always be empty (`.decompose()`) or will contain the extracted `tag` (`.extract()`).

#### How to fix?

First select the `tag` you like to remove from the tree, remove it and than select your `<h1>` to see the result.

#### Example (There is exactly one div with class brand in `item_detail_soup`)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<h1><div class="brand" style="display: block; font-size: 0.75rem;">Apple(#34567)</div>〔NEW〕 iPhone12 256GB </h1>'''
item_detail_soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

item_detail_soup.select_one('div.brand').extract() 
h1 = item_detail_soup.find('h1')
```

#### Example (There is more then one div with class brand in `item_detail_soup`)

Be aware that you just can use one option a time, so I commented the others out.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<h1><div class="brand" style="display: block; font-size: 0.75rem;">Apple(#34567)</div>〔NEW〕 iPhone12 256GB </h1>'''
item_detail_soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
for item in item_detail_soup.select('div.brand'):
    item.extract()
    #item.decompose()
    #item.replace_with('')
    
item_detail_soup.h1
```

#### Output

```
<h1>〔NEW〕 iPhone12 256GB </h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
item_detail_soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
for div in item_detail_soup .find_all("div", {'class':'brand'}): 
    div.decompose()
h1 = item_detail_soup.find("h1")
```